# What does it mean that our language is linear and finite?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy

In our everyday language, and in formal logic, our sentences and proofs are linear and finite. (Even if it has a tree structure, we usually write it down linearly on paper.) This seems to give a limit on what our logic can express. I can't say cleanly, but for example, the compactness theorem of first-order logic seems to be come from this kind of limitation. Do you have any ideas or reference for this?

Comment: Everything I can ever say is of finite length, at least in the word metric.

Comment: I don't think it is correct to say that first-order compactness comes from the fact that the language is finite and expressed linearly.  For example, sentences of second-order logic are also finite and expressed linearly, but compactness is very much not true for second-order logic.

Comment: Frege’s Begriffsschrift, the first first-order logic, was not linear. Peirce’s Diagrammatic Logic which also goes back to the baby stages of first-order logic, also isn’t linear. And, well, they don’t do anything linearly presented first-order logic doesn’t also do, but if you find either of them more intuitive (definitely not Begriffsschrift) then by all means learn it. Also being finite is not an issue at all, what is there to being infinite that cannot be described in a finite amount of text? Infinity is just an axiom, it’s not a thing anyone proved existed that we can’t understand entirely

Comment: @ChrisEagle: the meaning of semantic notions like "compactness" is somewhat nuanced for second-order logic. Can you explain what you mean by saying that compactness is not true for second-order logic.